# Convert line plots to barplot

Tags: r, plot

I've generated three line plots, but the data isn't really continuous, so I'd like to generate equivalent barplots, but my R knowledge is extremely lacking.

I have the following data.

```
> dat
     classifier depth   average
1         bayes     0 3.5639098
2         bayes     1 6.0000000
3         bayes     2 3.0253165
4         bayes     3 5.2250000
5         bayes     4 1.7931034
6         bayes     5 2.6800000
7         bayes     6 3.6551724
8      adaboost     0 9.2857143
9      adaboost     1 0.9733333
10     adaboost     2 0.4050633
11     adaboost     3 0.4750000
12     adaboost     4 0.3448276
13     adaboost     5 0.6000000
14     adaboost     6 0.4137931
15 randomforest     0 7.0375940
16 randomforest     1 0.8000000
17 randomforest     2 0.7341772
18 randomforest     3 1.2750000
19 randomforest     4 0.3103448
20 randomforest     5 0.3600000
21 randomforest     6 0.3448276
```

I use the following code to generate a plot.

```
dat <- read.table('depth_errors.data', sep=',',header=T)
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,6),ylim=c(0,10),xlab='depth',
     ylab='average misclassifications',type='n')

# Change the stroke
lines(dat[dat$classifier=='bayes',][,-1])
lines(dat[dat$classifier=='adaboost',][,-1],lty='dashed')
lines(dat[dat$classifier=='randomforest',][,-1],lty='dotted')

legend('topright', c('Naive Bayes', 'AdaBoost', 'Random Forest'), 
       lty=c('solid','dashed','dotted'))
```

This is the output (click to enlarge).

[image: average misclassifications]

As all my other plots have been generated with straight R, from a look and feel point of view I'd prefer a solution that doesn't use libraries like `ggplot`, though I'll take any advice I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@k_jacko](http://twitter.com/k_jacko), besides the labels on the x-axis, this is what I was after.

```
mat <- matrix(dat$average, nrow=3, byrow=T)

barplot(
  mat,
  ylim=c(0,10),
  xlab='depth',
  names.arg=levels(factor(dat$depth)),
  ylab='average misclassifications',
  beside=TRUE,
  legend.text=c('Naive Bayes', 'AdaBoost', 'Random Forest')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you decide to use the ggplot2 package:

This code

```
library(ggplot2)
dat$depth <- factor(dat$depth)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=depth, y=average, fill=classifier)) + geom_bar()
print(p)
```

Will produce:

[image]

and this code:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=depth, y=average, fill=classifier)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
print(p)
```

will produce this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great for reference, and ggplot certainly does produce much more attractive plots. But it would mean re-generating dozens of different plots, and I just want it done now. I'm sure it's something with my set up, but I also get an error with the above code, Error in aesdefaults(data, .$geom$default_aes(), mapped_vars) : could not find function "as_df"